# Jmeter variable filepath is not resolved in FileToString function

Tags: jmeter

I am using:

```
${__eval( ${__FileToString(${filePath}\x.xml)})}
```

to get an XML String from a file. The variable `filePath` is not resolved and I'm always getting the error "FileNotFound exception". If the absolute path is given, it works. It seems the variable is not resolved before the `FileToString` function call. Is there a way to use a relative path?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter uses [FileServer](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/services/FileServer.html) class to determine it's base directory.

If you look into JMeter log you'll be able to see something like:

```
2014/07/14 15:32:12 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Default base='/opt/jmeter/bin'
```

In my case it's `/opt/jmeter/bin`

So if I drop `x.xml` file into `/opt/jmeter/bin` folder it would be resolved via `${__FileToString(x.xml,,)}` function.

There is a property which can control base directory for relative paths resolution:

```
# Prefix used to identify filenames that are relative to the current base
#jmeter.save.saveservice.base_prefix=~/
```

You can set it to any other folder and JMeter will use it as the base for paths resolution.

The property can be changed in:

- *jmeter.properties* file
- *user.properties* file
- overriden via `-J` command-line argument as

  ```
  jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.base_prefix=c:/xml_payload/
  ```

jmeter.properties and user.properties files live under /bin folder of your JMeter installation, FileServer base is usually the same folder.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more details on JMeter tuning using properties.

Comment: Even though  could see the new path for jmeter.services.FileServer form the log, still I get the jmeter.functions.FileToString: Could not read file: :(